# How to use react-i18next when mapping data that comes not from the translation.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next, array.prototype.map

This is the array of objects that I want to map through. As you see, is also contains material-ui icon components. This is why I just can't map through the translation.json in locales

```
  const sidebarData = [

 {
      text: "Picken",
      icon: <GetAppIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/picken",
      title: "Artikel picken",
 },
 {
      text: "Hole Artikel",
      icon: <AddShoppingCartIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/holeartikel",
      title: "Hole Artikel zu dieser Workstation",
 },
 {
      text: "Hole Regal",
      icon: <ImportExportIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/holeregal",
      title: "Hole Regal zu dieser Workstation",
 }];
```

The locales for the english translation (locales/en/translation.json) looks like that:

```
{
 "sidebarmenu": {
      "jobliste": "Joblist",
      "picken": "Picken",
      "artikel": "Get Item",
      "regal": "Get Pod",
      "leer": "Get Storage",
      "karte": "Show Map"
 },
 "header": {
      "jobliste": "Joblist",
      "picken": "Pick Item",
      "artikel": "Get Item to this workstation",
      "regal": "Get Pod to this workstation",
      "leer": "Get empty storage to this workstation",
      "karte": "Show Warehouse Map"
 }
```

And the component looks like this:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
 import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
 import layouttheme from "./layouttheme";
 import ListAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ListAlt";
 import {Drawer,Typography,Divider,ListItemText,ListItem,List,Box,} from "@material-ui/core";
 import useStyles from "./LayoutStyles";
 import {useTranslation } from "react-i18next";


 function DrawerComp({ open, setOpen, sidebarData }) {

 const classes = useStyles();
 const history = useHistory();
 const [getPath, setGetPath] = useState("Jobliste");
 const { t } = useTranslation();

 function handleClick(item) {
      history.push(item.path);
      setGetPath(item.title);
 }

 
 return (
      <Drawer variant="persistent" anchor="left" open={open}>
           <List className={classes.sbList} sidebarData={sidebarData}>
                {sidebarData.map(item => (
                     <ListItem
                          key={item.text}
                          onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
                     >
                          <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                          <ListItemText>{item.text}</ListItemText>
                     </ListItem>
                ))}
           </List>
      </Drawer>
 );
 }

 export default DrawerComp;
```

So my question is how can connect the sidebarData with the translation.json in order to get the translation?

Answer (score 0):

You can either translate the `sidebarData` if this object is composed in a parent component:

```js
  const sidebarData = [{
      text: t("picken"),
      icon: <GetAppIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/picken",
      title: "Artikel picken",
 }, {
      text: t("hole_artikel"),
      icon: <AddShoppingCartIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/holeartikel",
      title: "Hole Artikel zu dieser Workstation",
 }, {
      text: t("hole_regal"),
      icon: <ImportExportIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/holeregal",
      title: "Hole Regal zu dieser Workstation",
 }];
```

You can also use the translation keys in the object instead of the full text. Then in your render function, wrap the properties with `t()`.

I personally don't like doing this, since you can't extract the translations with tools like [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner).

```js
  const sidebarData = [{
      text: "picken",
      icon: <GetAppIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/picken",
      title: "Artikel picken",
 }, {
      text: "hole_artikel",
      icon: <AddShoppingCartIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/holeartikel",
      title: "Hole Artikel zu dieser Workstation",
 }, {
      text: "hole_regal",
      icon: <ImportExportIcon style={{ fontSize: 35 }} />,
      path: "/holeregal",
      title: "Hole Regal zu dieser Workstation",
 }];
```

```js
 return (
      <Drawer variant="persistent" anchor="left" open={open}>
           <List className={classes.sbList} sidebarData={sidebarData}>
                {sidebarData.map(item => (
                     <ListItem
                          key={item.text}
                          onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
                     >
                          <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                          <ListItemText>{t(item.text)}</ListItemText>
                     </ListItem>
                ))}
           </List>
      </Drawer>
 );
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't use the translation keys in the object, since the whole object is in a different js-file, that is not a function component. So in this file (sidebarData.js) I can't use the {useTranslation}-Hook and then I got the error that "t" is not defined

Comment: Then the second option would work for you, right?

Comment: No it doesn't work.. but I'm not sure if I got it wrong: Does the second options mean that the data in my object is not changed, but instead I just writing this im my function component <ListItemText>{t(item.text)}</ListItemText>?

Comment: No, the `sidebarData` uses translation keys in the example I gave. You don't have to do this, but it matches the current translation convention that you are using.

Comment: Got it and it works. Really really cool! Thanks a lot!